# How to allow CORS in NodeJS 14

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, cors

I am new to Javascript and Node and I am trying to make a new Rest-based API using NodeJS.
But when I am trying to fetch the data using the API CORS issue is being thrown.

Error from browser console:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/feed/posts' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
Feed.js:53 GET http://localhost:8080/feed/posts net::ERR_FAILED
Feed._this.loadPosts @ Feed.js:53
componentDidMount @ Feed.js:37
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:19690
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:22662
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:189
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:238
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:291
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:22404
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:659
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11077
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22246
finishSyncRender @ react-dom.development.js:21663
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:21649
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21045
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:24194
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:24577
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:21763
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:24576
render @ react-dom.development.js:24659
./src/index.js @ index.js:8
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:782
fn @ bootstrap:150
0 @ validators.js:14
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:782
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
```

Here are the CORS-related settings which have been configured.

```
const express = require('express');


const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const feedRoutes = require('./routes/feed');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/feed', feedRoutes);


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');

    next();
});

app.listen(8080);
```

NPM and NodeJs version

```
(base) ➜  RestUsingNodeJs npm --version
7.18.1
(base) ➜  RestUsingNodeJs node --version
v14.17.0
```

Please suggest what needs to be done here.

Comment: Please go through this package, this should help you
[Package link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Comment: Thanks Nirjal But I have tried that and still the issue is coming. Is there anything else which can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set CORS before your request reaches the router. This will allow all the routes to be accessed anywhere on the web if that is what you need.
[this](https://stackabuse.com/handling-cors-with-node-js) resource might help you

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const feedRoutes = require('./routes/feed');

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');

    next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/feed', feedRoutes);

app.listen(8080);
```